# asp.net page with repeater and javascript used

Tags: javascript, asp.net, repeater

I am new with VB and combining JavaScript. This is easy question, but for a reason or other I am not able to figure it out.

I am not able to build IF-statement correctly. Please could you help me? I have looked and googled, but have not found such answer that would help me to get this correct. Otherwise my code works ok. Here is the code I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var markers = [
<asp:Repeater ID="rptMarkers" runat="server">
<ItemTemplate>
{
"title": '<%# Eval("pvm")%>',
"lat": '<%# Eval("lat")%>',
"lng": '<%# Eval("lng")%>',
"icon": '<%# Eval("Ikoni")%>',
"description": "<span style=’font-size:18px;font-weight:bold;><%#Eval("pvm")%> <%# Eval("Otsikko")%></span><hr>" +
"Text: <%# Eval("Nimi")%> <br> Merkki: <%# Eval("Tunniste")%> <br>"+
"<%# Eval("Info")%>"
```

--> This should be in IF-statetement; If there is "Photo" information this is taken along, but otherwise left out;

`+"</div><div><img src=<%# Eval("Photo")%>  height='150'></img></div></div>"`

<--

`}
</ItemTemplate>`
...

Please, given me some guidance.

Comment: It's not Java, it's JavaScript. Very different.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using VB, I think something like this should work:

```
+
<% If (Eval("Photo") <> String.Empty) Then %>
    '</div><div><img src="<%# Eval("Photo")%>"  height='150'></img></div></div>'
<% Else %>
    ''
<% End if %>
```

**EDIT:**

As the OP noted, the above doesn't work.  I now think it's going to be simpler to use a function that contains your business logic.  Something like this:

```
Public Function WriteJsObject(pvm As String,
                                lat As String,
                                lng As String,
                                icon As String,
                                description As String,
                                text As String,
                                nimi As String,
                                tunniste As String,
                                info As String,
                                photo As String) As String

    Dim jso As New StringBuilder("{")
    jso.AppendFormat("""title"": '{0}',{1}", pvm, vbCrLf)
    jso.AppendFormat("""lat"": '{0}',{1}", lat, vbCrLf)
    jso.AppendFormat("""lng"": '{0}',{1}", lng, vbCrLf)
    jso.AppendFormat("""icon"": '{0}'{1}", icon, vbCrLf)
    'the rest of your logic  here
    jso.AppendLine("}")
    Return jso.ToString

End Function
```

You'd use the function like this:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptMarkers" runat="server" >
    <HeaderTemplate>
        var markers = [
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%# Me.WriteJsObject(Eval("pvm"), Eval("lat"), Eval("lng"), Eval("icon"), Eval("description"), Eval("text"), Eval("nimi"), Eval("tunniste"), Eval("info"), Eval("photo")) %>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        ];
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: That extra </div> is suspicious to me and the apostrophes around the height could be misinterpreted.  Granted, that all came from the OP.  :)

Comment: Thanks. I used this code and I get error "Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be used in the context of a databound control." Other thing that I need hel is that I have path as <%# Eval("Path")%> and then photoname as <%# Eval("Photo")%>. How do I combine those?